# 18.10 upgrade issue

Tags: upgrade, 18.10

I have two different PCs, each multi-boot, with Ubuntu 18.04 as one of the operating systems on each.  When I run the 18.10 upgrade on either machine, it appears to be fully processing the upgrade, but when I reboot, it still says I'm on 18.04.  I've tried it both thru the GUI and thru the terminal, same result.  What gives?  Oddly, the report seems to show a completed upgrade, but under System>Details, it still says it's the last version (see screenshot).

dave@BigBoy:~$ ubuntu-report show

{
  "Version": "18.10",
  "OEM": 
{
    "Vendor": "To Be Filled By O.E.M.",

"Product": "To Be Filled By O.E.M."
  },

"BIOS": 
{
    "Vendor": "American Megatrends Inc.",

"Version": "P1.30"
  },

"CPU": 
{
    "OpMode": "32-bit, 64-bit",

```
"CPUs": "4",
"Threads": "1",

"Cores": "4",

"Sockets": "1",

"Vendor": "AuthenticAMD",

"Family": "16",

"Model": "4",

"Stepping": "3",

"Name": "AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor",

"Virtualization": "AMD-V"
```

},

"Arch": "amd64",
  "GPU": [

{
      "Vendor": "10de",
      "Model": "1244"
    }

],
  "RAM": 32.9,
  "Disks": 
[
    240.1,
    2000.4,
    2000.4,
    320.1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    15.6
  ],

"Partitions": [
    19.5,
    1,
    15.2
  ],

"Screens": [

{
      "Size": "598mmx336mm",
      "Resolution": "1920x1080",
      "Frequency": "60.00"
    }

],
  "Autologin": true,
  "LivePatch": false,
  "Session": 
{
    "DE": "Unity:Unity7:ubuntu",
    "Name": "unity",
    "Type": "x11"
  },

"Language": "en_US",

"Timezone": "America/New_York",

"Upgrade": {

"From": "18.04",

```
"InstallMedia": "Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \"Trusty Tahr\" - Beta amd64 (20150805)",

"Type": "GTK",
"ThirdPartySources": false,
"Stages": {

  "0": "start",

  "6": "PREPARE",

  "22": "MODIFY_SOURCES",

  "75": "FETCH",

  "193": "INSTALL",

  "199": "INSTALL",

  "356": "INSTALL",

  "15163": "POSTUPGRADE",

  "15370": "CLEANUP",

  "20526": "REBOOT"
}
```

}

dave@BigBoy:~$ ubuntu-report show | grep Version

"Version": "18.10",

```
"Version": "P1.30"
```

[image: screenshot of system>details after upgrade]

During the upgrade process, I did note some oddities toward the end (I often leave the terminal window open, and monitor it), where it would begin some process, hesitate, then come back with an error message about "no swap area available", when in fact I have about 8GB set aside specifically for swap.   That happened 4 or 5 times, near the end of the process.  After that, the upgrade finally acted as if it was finished and asked for a restart, but on rebooting and seeing that "18.04" still showing, I wasn't so sure everything had finished properly -- or if it had chickened out and reverted me to 18.04.

Comment: P;ease edit your question to include the complete output of `ubuntu-report show | grep Version`

Comment: So your problem is with the logo only?

Comment: It sounds even sillier when you put it that way, but if the upgrade did complete the way it should, why is it not reflected in system>details?

Comment: What do you get with `lsb_release -cdir`?

Comment: ~$ lsb_release -cdir 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 18.10 
Release: 18.10 
Codename: cosmic       ......which all looks good, so why the discrepancy elsewhere?

Comment: I've found the "correct" logo, in /usr/share/unitygreeter, but apparently the system is just pulling an old one, instead of the correct one.  Weird, but not fatal.  I'll keep looking for the location of the wrong logo, and see if I can replace it with the right one.

Comment: The incorrect logo, from 18.04, is stuck in usr/share/unity-control-center/ui, and that's what it's pulling to display.  So for the time being, since everything else is apparently kosher, I simply copied that old logo, edited it to say "ubuntu 18.10" (you could probably use GIMP, but I'm more familiar with PhotoFiltre), then used terminals to rename the old logo "UbuntuLogoOLD.png", and copied in the revised one.  (sudo required, of course, since that's a write-protected folder.)  Problem solved.  Call me anal-retentive.